# No such file or directory when attempting to save the key

Tags: ssh

I am attempting to create a new ssh key for my new linux server on my MacOS and I am wondering why I am getting the following error:

```
➜  Projects ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa): .ssh/1st_key
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Saving key ".ssh/1st_key" failed: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to specify a folder, it will automatically save it in .ssh in your home dir. It only asks for a filename (that does not contain . or /)